# Monitor stays black after plugging it in

Tags: 12.04, lightdm, monitor

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 on a PC using lightdm. When I have the monitor plugged in from the start the system boots just fine and everything works as expected. When I plug off the monitor, the system is still working fine (it is reacting to keyboard and mouse input - I tested it playing some music). Once I plug it in again, the system seems to be in a frozen state, showing only a black screen but I can still move and see the mouse.
I can actually right click and the right click menu pops up as if I clicked on the desktop. I can also go to the "change desktop background" menu, but everything is really slow and except of the newly drawn dialogs/windows, everything else still stays black.

I can still switch to any virtual terminal (Ctrl+Alt+F1-F6) but switching back (Ctrl+Alt+F7) results again in a black screen and only the mouse pointer.

Neither the Xorg.0.log nor the lightdm/lightdm.log file contains anything suspicious. (I can post it if it is of interest).

Running `sudo restart lightdm` will get me back to the login screen and everything is working well again - except all programs that ran before are gone.

How can I either prevent the black screen issue, or alternatively jump right back into my session - I have programs running that shouldn't be interrupted or restarted by this.